# Migration from closure library to Dart

Tags: dart, google-closure-compiler

I was wondering if there are any tips or documents describing dart workflow to easily migrate from Closure tools background to Dart. I am especially interested in a replacement for soy templates and internationalization. What would you suggest for those as well for some of the bigger parts there (like control / component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a brief look at Closure tools documentation and soy templates.
I haven't seen something similar in Dart.

Dart i18n is WIP and still a bit rough around the edges.

The best template/component technologies available for Dart are IMHO AngularDart and PolymerDart
but I don't think there is an easy migration path.

Answer (score 1):

The Dart internationalization library is modeled after Closure's, so it's probably a pretty easy replacement, although not everything is finished yet.